# External connection in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, hosting

I have deployed an ASP.NET application on 1&1 hosting provider (https://www.ionos.com/). While that application works fine with the SQL Server database hosted on 1&1, I need to read and write some data from MySQL hosted on Google Cloud VPC.

The code (for MySQL) works great on my local system but from 1&1's server, it can not connect to the MySQL DB on Google cloud, seems like 1&1 won't let me connect to outside systems. I am not sure what kind of connection settings I will have to do, any help in this? Maybe some proxy settings in `web.config`?

Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Only 1&1 will be able to help you, the most probable is that outgoing ports aren't routed to the Internet.

Comment: Is there any error message that you see? Could you please check your connection strings again?

Comment: Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond